# How can I hide a horizontal scrollbar if overflow-x has to be visible?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a navigation bar that consists of an outer and an inner div. The outer div is styled with display: flex; justify-content: center and has a mandatory overflow-x: auto.

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <!-- nav items that may overflow the parent -->
  </div>
</div>
```

The issue I'm facing is that when the content in the 'inner' div overflows, a horizontal scrollbar appears due to the overflow-x: auto on the outer div. I want to hide this scrollbar while retaining scrolling ability.

I attempted to hide the scrollbar using the following CSS:

A)

```
.inner::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

B)

```
.inner::-webkit-scrollbar {
    scrollbar-width: 0;
    scrollbar-height: 0;
    scrollbar-color: transparent transparent;
}
```

However, this solution doesn't seem to work, possibly due to the overflow-x: auto on the outer div. I've researched numerous similar issues, but my situation is unique because the overflow-x property on the outer div must remain as auto, visible, or initial.

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!